# How do I enlarge fonts for GTK applications?

Tags: linux, gtk

I ran a program under WINE and when it terminated, suddenly lots of programs were running with tiny fonts, including Google Chrome, Unison, and PLT Scheme.  I think what these programs have in common is they all use GTK.  I am running Debian Linux without a Gnome desktop.  As suggested on the web, I put this text in `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
style "user-font"
{
    font_name="BitStreamVeraSans 14"
}
widget_class "*" style "user-font"
gtk-font-name="BitStreamVeraSans 14"
```

Unfortunately this change has had no discernible effect.

**How can I escape the land of tiny-fonted ones?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked down the problem and in the end it was a combination of GTK and other factors.  Somehow WINE changed the physical screen size as reported by `xdpyinfo`.  As a result the DPI was computed to be 56—way too small.

The solution was to change the X server to use the correct size by running `xrandr --screen 0 --fbmm 287x180`.

Comment: This fixed my fonts after removing some gnome packages in debian. What exactly does changing the fbmm do?